# Reciprocal links or text based links

Tags: seo, links, blog

I have a blog and I've found someone else who has a blog with the same subject as mine.
We want to do reciprocal links in the blogs.

I read in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_building#Reciprocal_link) that reciprocal links aren't good for the Google. Is it true? Would it be better if we indicate links in posts with specific keywords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reciprocal links (especially site wide) are not as efficient compared to several years ago.

Nowadays, a good link exchange would be a text link from a post content (in the beginning if possible) by using your brand names as anchor text (to make the link almost natural). The two links can point to the home page of the other site:

1. One link from a blog post of the site A pointing to the home page of the site B
2. One link from a blog post of the site B pointing to the home page of the site A

Moreover, make sure the theme of the two websites is close as possible and these links can help visitors of the websites.

Otherwise, using keywords as anchor text for the links can be penalizing if you have many links like this; that's why I advise you to use your brand names.

Comment: One or two reciprocal links here or there on just a few sites is not bad of course. You are right about site wide links in that there some danger. I like conversational links more than branded links simply because they are more effective for CTR and it is an opportunity to rank for keywords or long-tail keywords. However, branded links are sometimes the right thing to do especially when the content is about a brand or product. I like to recommend where ever possible to create a deep-link simply because there are enough junk sites linking to your home page already. It adds value.

Answer (score 2):

Reciprocal links are just bad if it’s been overused. You can only link to other pages as long as it’s relevant to your website. Try to link to other sites that will help to improve your backlinks naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Reciprocal linking is not much effective after Google updates. If you really want to generate backlink of your website then do blog commenting in your niche blogs and submit your blog in different blog directories. I think it will give you better result than reciprocal linking.